# Deployed GAE Instance Does Not Have Permissions

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, permissions, google-secret-manager

I have successfully deployed `apollo-server-express` on a GAE instance, however, the instance is **unable to fetch secrets from the Google Secrets Manager**.

Error from GAE Logs:

```bash
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

index.ts

```
// @note `SECRET_NAMES` is a comma separated string of the secrets' paths
const secretNames = process.env.SECRET_NAMES?.split(',') ?? []
for (const secretName of secretNames) {
  // @note `loadSecret` will use Google Secrets Manager SDK to download the payload
  // @note `secretName` is the fully qualified path to the secret located in Google Secret Manager API
  Object.assign(process.env, await loadSecret(secretName))
}
```

app.yml

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16
service: <service-name>
instance_class: F1
env_variables:
  SECRET_NAMES: '<path-1>/versions/latest,<path-2>/versions/latest`
```

On my local machine, I would use the `google-service-key.json` to have the server run with an app service's credentials as default. This app service has the following roles:

- Secrets Access
- SQL Client

However, once I run `gcloud app deploy`, the server is no longer going to look for the `google-service-key.json`, and instead will use `admin.credentials.applicatioDefault()` to authenticate.

However, I'm not certain that the default credentials of the GAE instance are the same credentials that I referenced in the `google-service-key.json`.